# subtract two datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I use these following codes in the winform for subtracting two datetime. these are complete datetime which includes day and month and year in it. I want to know how can I subtract two date time only with day and month. For example subtract of 5/12 and 6/12 without any year in it.

```
        DateTime date1 = new DateTime(byear, bmonth, bday, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime datenow =  DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan timeSpan = datenow - date1;
```

Please give me some codes so that I can subtract two datetime with its day and month.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about leap years? In other words what you are trying to do is meaningless.

Comment: Is "5/12" the 5th of December or the 12th of May?

Comment: @MarkByers month is 5 and day is 12

Comment: @aliboy38, I think David means that if you're subtracting Feb 27 from March 1, your result will be different depending on what year it is (whether it is a leap year and Feb 29th needs to be taken into account).

Comment: What you posted is exactly what you should do.

Comment: @Brandon It must show the result like 4. No problem with the year dude

Comment: @aliboy38 In other words you want the subtraction to be made in the context of a year that is not a leap year?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(year, month1 , day1);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(year, month2,  day2);
int days = (int) Math.Round((dt1 - dt2).TotalDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some default year like datetime.now and do the subtraction like normal.
This wouldnt work for non leap years though as 2012 is leap year.

```
 DateTime dt1= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month1, day1);
 DateTime dt2= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month2, day2);
 TimeSpan t= dt1 - dt2;
```

Comment: I would avoid calling `DateTime.Now.Year` twice because it is non-deterministic and you could get a different result the second time.